# Connect4 game board class

Tags: c++, game

I'm making a connect4 game in c++ and so far i have almost got the board class done

before I continue coding i want your thoughts on what I should improve because
i definently feel like this could be way simpler

````
class Board {
  public: enum Type {
    player1,
    player2,
    empty
  };

  private:
    std::array<std::array<Type, 7>, 6> m_board{};

    std::string getCellColor(Type type) {
      switch (type) {
        case Type::player1: return "\033[1;33m O\033[0m"; // red
        case Type::player2: return "\033[1;31m O\033[0m"; // yellow
        case Type::empty: return "\033[1;30m O\033[0m"; // black
      }
    }

  public:
    Board() {
      for (int cols{0}; cols < 7; ++cols) {
        for (int rows{0}; rows < 6; ++rows) {
          m_board[rows][cols] = Type::empty;
        }
      }
    }

    void print() {
      std::for_each(m_board.begin(), m_board.end(), [this](auto& col) {
        std::cout << '\t';
        std::for_each(col.begin(), col.end(), [this](auto& cell) {
          std::cout << getCellColor(cell);
        });
        std::cout << '\n';
      });
    };

    void hit(int col) {
      // the length of a col is 6
      // so for example if a col has been "hit" twice 
      // then the freeCell is 4 because the 4th index is the first one empty
      // the first cell on the column that is not already hit
      int freeCell{getColDepth(col) - 1};
      m_board[freeCell][col] = Type::player1;
    };

    // returns how many cells are not empty in that column
    int getColDepth(int col) {
      int depth{};
      // start loop at top of col
      for (int row{0}; row < 6; ++row) {
        if (m_board[row][col] != Type::empty) return row;
      }
      // if no hits
      return 6;
    };
};
```
````